# How to copy a file from host to a GPU device?

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

I have a C code which reads a file filled with data separated in chunks (called frames), then takes each frame and saves it in a vector - each frame is a vector component. Now I want to do the same thing with CUDA, so that my program reads and saves each frame in a parallelized way. So first I need to copy the data file from the host to a GPU device.

I was thinking to do this with cudaMalloc, but I was wondering if there is any other way to copy the file from host to device.

I guess this is a straightforward thing to do, but I'm just starting with CUDA.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might want to study the CUDA vectorAdd sample code.

Comment: I might be confused by what you are trying to do, but maybe SCP is what you are looking for? https://haydenjames.io/linux-securely-copy-files-using-scp/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stealing, but that's not what I need. I edited my question, trying to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella . That summing-vectors example is exactly what I am trying to do with my data file, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU has a different memory and you need to copy everything to it.
The first thing you need to do is `cudaMalloc` to give you space.
Then you copy data using `cudaMemcpy`.

BONUS: There is also `cudaMallocManaged` which manages the copy to/from device automatically. It is good if you don't want to deal with `cudaMemcpy`.

Below is a simple way of working with CUDA:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double * data_host = new double[N];

    // read your data here and put it in "data_host"
    // ...


    // allocate and copy your data to device
    double * data_gpu;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &data_gpu, N * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(data_gpu, data_host, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // launch kernel
    kernel<<< number_of_blocks, number_of_threads>>> (data_gpu);

    // copy back the result
    cudaMemcpy(data_host, data_gpu, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Do more stuff with your data
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer!